# How to pass the two parameter in onclick function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am using AJAX,onload this ajax working fine after that i displaying results , in this results i have one button called contac,from this button i passed statically two parameter (2,5). insteed of that i want to pass my **id** and **name**, i tried i am not able to do,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:"http://www.domain.com/",
data:data,
success: function(data) {
//console.log(data);
  var count = data.length;
 if(count > 0)
 {
   var htmlString='';
   $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
  var name = value.name;  
  var availableFrom = value.availableFrom;  
  var postedBy = value.postedBy; 
  if(postedBy == "ROLE_AGENT"){
   var postedBy = "Agent";
  }else if(postedBy == "ROLE_OWNER"){
   var postedBy = "Owner";
  }else{
   var postedBy = "Builder";
  }       
  var superBuiltupArea = value.superBuiltupArea;  
  var superBuiltupAreaUnit = value.superBuiltupAreaUnit; 
  //var sqFt =  superBuiltupArea+' '+superBuiltupAreaUnit;
  var price = value.expectedPrice;
   htmlString+='<div class="row" id="prptylstt"><div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;"><a href="propertydetails.php?id='+value.id+'"><img src="pics/02.jpg"style="width:100%;height:170px;"/  > </a></div><div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;"><h4  style="color:#000;padding-top:12px;">'+name+'</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3"><p class="parclr">Price</p><h4 class="colrh" ><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 22.70L</h4></div><div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr" ><p class="parclr">Sqft</p><h4 class="colrh" >'+superBuiltupArea+'</h4></div><div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr" ><p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p><h4 class="colrh" ></i>'+availableFrom+'</h4></div><div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr"> <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p><h4 class="colrh" >'+postedBy+'</h4></div></div><hr><div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;"><div class="col-sm-3" ><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>>Quick View</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 " > <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 " ></div><div class="col-sm-3 "><div class="contact" style="text-align:center;">';
   
  // htmlString+='<button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact">Contact</button>';
 
   htmlString+='<button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction(2,5)">Contact</button>';
   
   htmlString+='</div></div></div></div></div>';
   
 });
 $('#prop_listing').empty().append(htmlString);
 $("#search_not_found").hide();
 }
 else{
 $("#search_not_found").show();
 $("#prop_listing").hide();
 }
},
error:function(exception){
console.log('Exeption:'+exception);
}
}); 
});
```

Comment: from where you get the 2 parameters in your page !!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have variables called `id` and `name`, you can do something like

```
htmlString += '<button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction("+id+","+name+")">Contact</button>';
```

or

```
htmlString += `<button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction(${id},${name})">Contact</button>`;
```

Comment: If  i clcik  button that getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Mr @Abel Tadesse U have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

How about `myFunction.bind(this, 2, 5)`

something like

`htmlString += <button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction.bind(this, 2, 5)()">Contact</button>;`

example:
http://jsbin.com/supuye/edit?html,js,console,output